# Form action ,capture the response

Tags: php, jquery

I'm making a jquery mobile app where i need to upload an image so I used this code:

```
<form action="http://tipsnow.altervista.org/upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                Title: <input type="text" name="title" id="title" />
                Question Text: <input type="text" name="text" id="text" />
                <input type="hidden" id="idUtente" name="idUtente" value="">
                Select image to upload:
                <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
                <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
            </form>
```

now i would need somehow to get the echo from the php which tells me it uploading succeded or no,how can i do it?

@Edit
Here's some of the the php

```
<?php 
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
//here i insert the info into db
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Please post your php content

Comment: please share some php code,what else you did upload.php

Answer (score 0):

Here's the basic example of how you can do it using php, understand it, and improve it from here.

It may not the direct answer of what you need, but its the good start.

this php code return a json encode

```
<?php  
if ( isset($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']) ) {
  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'], "path/to/upload/{$_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']}")) {
    $data['res'] =  "Success";
    echo json_encode($data);
  } else {
    $data['res'] = "Failed";
    echo json_encode($data);
  }
}
```

?>

and this jquery, will catch the json return by the php

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#submit').click(function() {
    var url = $(this).parent('form').attr('action');
    $.ajax({
      url:      url,
      type:     'post',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: $('form').serialize(),
      success:  function(data) {
        alert(data.res);
      }
      error:    function(data) {
        alert('error');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Hope this help

Comment: yeah but how do I get the echo into a var from jquery

Comment: You need an ajax for that

Comment: if i do a call like that , in the php can i get the values from input with $_POST['idUtente'];  ?